# Prove the given two integrals are not equal

Tags: probability, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

I am stuck with following problem:

Prove the following two integrals are not equal:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(y-c)\log \big(p(y-c)+p(y+c)\big)dy \neq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(y+c)\log \big(p(y-c)+p(y+c)\big)dy
$$
where $c\in\mathbb{R}^{+*}$. $p(\cdot)$ is the gaussian mixture and has the following form:
$$
p(x) = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_1^2}}+\frac{1-a}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_2^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}}
$$
where $0<a<0.5$, and $\mu>0$. Obviously, if $\mu=0$, $p(x)$ would be symmetric and the equality would hold.

The difficulty of this problem is the integral of log-sum-exp which is hard to solve. I wonder if there is a way to show one is greater/less than the other? Thanks for your time in advance.